# Stuck on angularjs ng-checked

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-filters

I'm trying to implement that when a user clicks a check box it displays all products in the ng-repeat with a quantity of 0.  Else when the check box is not check all items display.  Currently I was able to get half the functionality.

Check box :

```
<input type="checkbox" name="onoffswitch" class="onoffswitch-checkbox" id="myonoffswitch" ng-checked="vm.OnHandQty()">
```

Table

```
    <tr ng-repeat="item in vm.items | filter :search">                                           
        <td ng-bind="item.itemNo"> </td>
        <td ng-bind="item.description"></td>
        <td ng-bind="(item.listPrice | currency)"></td>
        <td ng-bind="item.onHandQty" ng-model="quantity"></td>
    </tr>
```

Controller

```
    vm.OnHandQty = function () {               
    $scope.search = {};

    vm.items.forEach(i => {
        if (i.onHandQty == 2) {
            console.log(i);
            $scope.search = i;
            return true;
        }
        else {
            $scope.search =i;
            return false;
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would propose changing the implementation of your checkbox and controller:

Checkbox

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="vm.checked" name="onoffswitch" class="onoffswitch-checkbox" id="myonoffswitch">
```

- Here, we use "ng-model" instead of "ng-checked" and  "vm.checked" is a variable that you define as the ng-model for your checkbox.

Controller

```
$scope.search = function(item) {
    return ($scope.vm.checked) ? item.onHandQuantity === 0: true;
};
```

- Here, we define the "ng-repeat" filter that you are using in your table.

Comment: This removes all objects on the check and on uncheck places them back

Comment: Edited my answer. I had forgotten to include "item" has an input into the search function

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
<tr ng-repeat="item in vm.items" ng-show="onoffswitch==true && item.onHandQty != 0? false : true">
    <td ng-bind="item.itemNo"> </td>
    <td ng-bind="item.description"></td>
    <td ng-bind="(item.listPrice | currency)"></td>
    <td ng-bind="item.onHandQty" ng-model="quantity"></td>
</tr>
```

This will only show the row if `onoffswitch` is true and if the `onHandQty` is zero, otherwise it will show the row.  So the row will be hidden if `onoffswitch` is true and `onHandQty` is not zero.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of **ng-change** and **ng-model**.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="onoffswitch" class="onoffswitch-checkbox" id="myonoffswitch" ng-model="vm.checked" ng-change="checkBoxChange(vm.checked)">
```

Then, from you checkBoxChange function, apply your business logic:

```
vm.checkBoxChange = function(checked){
   if(checked){
      //Do something
   }else{
     //Something else
    }
};
```